# Using a ValidationAttribute with a nested class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following class in my ViewModel:

```
public class ParentClass
{
    public string Selection { get; set; }

    [MyValidation]
    public string ParentProperty { get; set; }

    public NestedClass Nested { get; set; }

    public class NestedClass
    {
        [MyValidation] //this doesn't have context of ParentClass inside MyValidation attribute
        public string NestedProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and the following ValidationAttribute:

```
public class MyValidation : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        ParentClass parentClass = (ParentClass)validationContext.ObjectInstance;

        if (parentClass.Selection.Equals("New"))
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Required");
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

`[MyValidation]` works correctly on `ParentClass` properties. However, when I put it on a `NestedClass` property, I get an error:

`InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'NestedClass' to type 'ParentClass'.`

Is there a way I can access the `ParentClass.Selection` value inside `[MyValidation]` while still being able to put `[MyValidation]` on `NestedClass` properties?

Comment: `NestedClass` does not inherit from `ParentClass`, your attribute trys to cast to `ParentClass`.  This will not work.

Comment: @maccettura `NestedClass` is inside `ParentClass` ... it is in my example.

Comment: Looks like `validationContext` could also be of type `NestedClass` because you are using `MyValidation` also at the `NestedProperty`. So some casts will fail.

Comment: The thing is that you're trying to use your validation with the nested class, but your `NestedClass` doesn't inherit from `ParentClass` and inside your `IsValid` method  in `MyValidation` class you try to cast the object instance to a `ParentClass` on the first line inside of the method. This will trhow the exception because you can cast an object of `NestedClass` type to `ParentClass` type. You should use Generics to make the validation, or make the `NestedClass` inherit from ParentClass.

Comment: @RyanBuening I somehow missed it on my first glance, I modified my comment to tell you your problem.

Comment: If make `NestedClass` inherit  from `ParentClass` by doing `public class NestedClass : ParentClass` I get a `NullReferenceException` on `if (parentClass.Selection.Equals("New"))`. How would I go about referencing `ParentClass`?

Comment: Short answer is no. `ValidationContext` is the current context - i.e. `NestedClass`, not `ParentClass`